# Fechar uma janela em php e atualizar a antiga

Tags: php, javascript, html

Galera... não estou usando janela flutuante e nem modal nada do tipo, meu TCC ficou com um problema e pelo curto prazo pra terminar não consegui usar esse método. Oque eu preciso é de um código que feche a janela que foi aberta e atualize a antiga. vou postar o meu código. já tentei diversas funções em Javascript mas todas fecham a janela imediatamente após serem abertas.
Funciona desse jeito, tenho um cadastro de notas fiscais e nesse cadastro tenho um botão para incluir credores de notas, ao clicar nele abre uma janela no browser mesmo uma janela separada, então nesta janela o usuário informa o Nome do Credor da nota e seu CNPJ, após a inserção quero que a janela seja fechada e então atualizada a janela Notas Fiscais onde tem um combobox que lista todos os credores cadastrados. Por favor me ajudem... 
[image: Código JavaScript para chamar a nova Tela]

[image: Código HTML do botão da página Notas Fiscais que chama a tela Incluir Credor]

Esse é o código do botão que chama a janela...

[image: Código Janela Incluir Credor...]

Como não sabia oque vocês precisam... mandei o código inteiro da janela que é aberta e somente o código do botão que a chama...
Desde Já eu agradeço.... ah outro detalhe... estou usando bootstrap...

Comment: Mesmo se Thomas da a reposta coreta (vou colocar um +1) o problema MAIOR e a pergunta.
Vc NAO PODE FECHAR UMA JANELA EM PHP!!!! 
O PHP a um linguagem "lado servidor": cria codigo HTML o Javascript.
Precisa perfeitamente entender isso, porque se nao, vc vai procurar as respostas no lugar errado: vc pode gastar 50 dias procurando um funçao em PHP que vai fechar uma janela, quando vai precisar de somente 10 segundos para buscar esta funcçao, se vc busca "fechar janela javascript".
Observa a resposta de Thomas: e Javascript. NAO PHP!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No código da sua página `inc_credor.php`, coloque o seguinte:

```
<script>
    window.onunload = fechaEstaAtualizaAntiga;
    function fechaEstaAtualizaAntiga() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792408/open-popup-and-refresh-parent-page-on-close-popup

Comment: Valeu amigo... deu certo... só coloquei a mais um window.close(); que dai deu certo exatamente como eu queria... obrigado...